# Resultant of two special trinomials

Tags: polynomials, resultant

Consider $f(x)=x^n-x^s-1$ and $g(x)=x^i-x^j-1$ , I want to find $Resultant(f,g)$. It is well known that it is determinant of a Sylvester matrix but, I am finding it to obscure to evaluate in that way. Is there some known result for such special cases ?

Comment: It would be better to use different notation for the two polynomials, say $f(x)$  and $g(x)$.

Comment: Shift your problem to mathoverflow

Comment: Done – https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269891/resultant-of-two-special-trinomials